# Kivy application looks different on Mac

Tags: user-interface, kivy

My Kivy application has a different look under Mac than under Windows or Linux. What could be the reason behind this ? The screen resolution ? The installation process under different OS ? ... ?

Here is the code for the first page:

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<MenuButton>:
    font_size: 20
    size_hint: None, None
    height: 75
    width: 300
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}

MyScreenManager:
    HomePage:

#### Home Page ##############################################
<HomePage>:
    name: 'Home'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: 50
        padding: 20 
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: 1, 0.23
            Label:
                text: 'V2G-Sim'
                font_size: 50
            Label:
                text: 'Vehicle to Grid Simulator'
                font_size: 30

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: 1, 0.64
            spacing: 20
            RelativeLayout:
                MenuButton:
                    text: 'Create vehicles'
                    on_release: 
                        app.root.transition.direction = 'left'  
                        app.root.current = 'Itinerary'
            RelativeLayout:
                MenuButton:
                    text: 'Grid initialization'
                    on_release: 
                        app.root.transition.direction = 'left'  
                        app.root.current = 'Grid'
            RelativeLayout:
                MenuButton:
                    text: 'Simulate vehicles'
                    on_release: 
                        app.root.transition.direction = 'left'  
                        app.root.current = 'SimulationType'
            RelativeLayout:
                MenuButton:
                    text: 'Visualizations'
                    on_press:
                        root.raise_popup()
                    on_release: 
                        root.visualization()

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: 1, 0.13
            spacing: 30
            Button:
                text: 'Project status'
                font_size: 20
                size_hint: 0.7, 1
                on_release: 
                    app.root.transition.direction = 'left'  
                    app.root.current = 'ProjectStatus'
            Button:
                text: 'Exit'
                font_size: 20
                size_hint: 0.7, 1
                on_release:
                    root.exit_app()
```

Here is the look under a Windows/Linux distribution:[image]

Here is the look under Mac (tested with 2 different Mac book)
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mac probably has a high dpi display, so your fixed size declarations for the buttons and font size are half the actual size since they're given in pixels.

You can use the `dp` function from kivy.metrics (automatically imported in kv) to avoid this, e.g. `font_size: dp(20)`.

Note that screens are all a bit different and may not have their dpi reported correctly anyway, so you will probably still get some (smaller) differences with different hardware.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out this myself yesterday. I was pretty surprised that the default unit was in pixel. Also I used **sp** instead of **dp** to be sure that user's settings would be taken in account. Thanks though.